# Is "as much as the next guy" a simile?

Tags: terminology, literary-device, rhetorical-devices, figurative, simile

Would "as much as the next guy" be a simile, or just an idiom?  I am working on a lesson plan for similes, and was not 100% sure.

Comment: I'm not even sure it's an idiom, since it means pretty much what it says, although "the next guy" requires some interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I argue it is not.  The simple description of a simile is a figurative comparison using "like" or "as," however these words can be used for literal comparisons as well as (see what I did there?) figurative ones.

For example, one might say that a tall, narrow bottle appears larger than a short, wide bottle at first glance.  But really each has a one quart capacity.  The one holds *as much as* the other.  This is clearly not a simile.

In parallel, a statement like "I appreciate theater as much as the next guy" is making a comparison between mine "the next guy's" capacity for enjoying the theater.  While the next guy might be a figurative entity, the comparison between the measurements is not.

Comment: 'As black as coal' has a literal rather than figurative meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/simile) definition of simile is

> simile n
>
> 1 a figure of speech involving the comparison of one thing with
>   another thing *of a different kind*, used to make a description more
>   emphatic or vivid  [emphasis mine]

Here, 'the next guy' is hardly 'of a different kind' in any meaningful sense, and the 'used to make a description more
emphatic or vivid' requirement is not fulfilled.